# Is it possible to rebase branches along with their unmerged child branches in git?

Tags: git

I have a project and its repository with the following branching model:

- *master*
- ↳ *dev*
- ↳ *feature-####*
- ↳ *subtask-####-####*

Because of pull requests, every commit is encouraged to be merged to its parent branch without fast-forwarding (done via the web-interface)

- *subtask-####-####* ⮕ *feature-####*
- *feature-####* ⮕ *dev*
- *dev* ⮕ *master*

For example,

```
  * merge feature-2 into dev
  |\
  | * merge subtask 2-1 into feature-2
  | |\
  | | * subtask 2-1
  | |/
  | * feature-2
  |/
  |
  |   * subtask 1-3 (the subtask is not done yet)
  |  /
  | * merge subtask-1-2 into feature-1
  | |\
  | | * subtask 1-2
  | | * subtask 1-2
  | |/
  | * merge subtask-1-1 into feature-1
  | |\
  | | * subtask-1-1
  | |/
  | * feature-1
  |/
  * dev
 /
* master
.
.
.
```

Now suppose I want to rebase the not-yet-completed `feature-1` branch onto the `dev` branch where the `feature-2` branch is already merged to (it's considered safe because the feature branches are supposed not to change the same code).
The way I see it is:

```
git checkout feature-1
git rebase -p dev # now the feature-1 branch is on-top of the dev branch preserving the merges
git checkout subtask-1-3
git rebase -p feature-1
```

But the last command fails with the following output:

> error: commit cd801c0b02c9a2a27c58ab6e3245bf526099f12c is a merge but no -m option was given.
>   fatal: cherry-pick failed
>   Could not pick cd801c0b02c9a2a27c58ab6e3245bf526099f12c

As far as I understand, `rebase` uses `cherry-pick` under the hood and the latter requires the `-m` flag, and this flag is not passed with `rebase`.
I'm not sure, but simple `git rebase --continue` seems to be a work around it and the history seems to be kept according to the branching model.
`git rebase --continue` might be required to be executed a few times until the rebase completes.

My questions are:

- Is it safe to rebase the history this way to avoid merge-tangled history?
- How do I tell git not to stop for cherry-picking merge commits during rebase, and are my assumptions regarding `git rebase --continue` correct?
- Or, if it's ever possible, how do I rebase the whole feature branch along with its *all* unmerged child branches onto a new commit of its parent branch? For example, I would like to rebase the whole `feature-1` with `subtask-1-3`  automatically. I understand that git does not have a *this-is-a-parent/child-branch* concept, but any way to specify the relations between the branches would be perfectly fine.

My git version is `git version 2.15.1`.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible: yes. Easy: no, especially when the graph is complex.

Comment: @torek Well yes, I just meant a way of doing that in at least semi-automatic manner, so I could get rid of doing the same for each such branch. Perhaps I need to write another script for this and integrate it into my Git aliases, but I'm not sure how do I deal with possible text conflicts and (cherry-picking) errors that are similar to what I faced in the post.

Comment: I started on such a thing once (when there was a reason to do it) and got bogged down in the details and just took care of the immediate problems manually and never got back to it. It wasn't clear to me what the right way(s) to script it were...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a Python script the can implement this.
The script is **NOT** well-tested, but it seems to work fine for non-conflict cases.

The concept behind the script is relations between branches.
A directed graph is generated from the relations in order to calculate the rebase order.
The relations are stored in `./.git/xrebase-topology`.
However, there some potentially **dangerous** or even **destructive** cases:

- If there are conflicts, the script aborts suggesting to resolve conflicts, proceed with merge or rebase and then re-run the script.
- The script does not seem to work fine with empty commits.

Install:

```sh
ln -s "$(pwd)/git-xrebase" "$(git --exec-path)/git-xrebase"
```

Uninstall:

```sh
rm "$(git --exec-path)/git-xrebase"
```

For the repo I asked for the associations are generated with:

```sh
git xrebase add master dev
git xrebase add dev feature-1
git xrebase add feature-1 subtask-1-1 subtask-1-2 subtask-1-3
```

Then the `dev` branch and its descendants can be rebased by a single command:

```sh
git xrebase rebase dev
```

Example output for the perfect case:

```
master<-dev: checkout to dev
master<-dev: rebase...
dev<-feature-1: checkout to feature-1
dev<-feature-1: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: checkout to subtask-1-1
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-2: checkout to subtask-1-2
feature-1<-subtask-1-2: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-3: checkout to subtask-1-3
feature-1<-subtask-1-3: rebase...
done
master<-dev: checkout to dev
master<-dev: rebase...
dev<-feature-1: checkout to feature-1
dev<-feature-1: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: checkout to subtask-1-1
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-2: checkout to subtask-1-2
feature-1<-subtask-1-2: rebase...
done
master<-dev: checkout to dev
master<-dev: rebase...
dev<-feature-1: checkout to feature-1
dev<-feature-1: rebase...
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: checkout to subtask-1-1
feature-1<-subtask-1-1: rebase...
done
master<-dev: checkout to dev
master<-dev: rebase...
dev<-feature-1: checkout to feature-1
dev<-feature-1: rebase...
done
```

#### git-xrebase.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections
import git
import itertools
import os
import re
import sys

__repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories = True)
__git = git.cmd.Git(__repo.working_tree_dir)
__topology_file_path = os.path.join(__repo.working_tree_dir, '.git', 'xrebase-topology')

class __XRebaseException(Exception):
    pass

def __peek(callback, sequence):
    for e in sequence:
        callback(e)
        yield e

def __read_file_lines(path, ignore_no_file = False):
    if not ignore_no_file and not os.path.isfile(path):
        return
        yield
    l = len(os.linesep)
    for line in open(path, 'r'):
        yield line[:-l] if line.endswith(os.linesep) else line

def __write_file_lines(path, lines):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line)
            file.write(os.linesep)

class ParentAndChild:

    def __init__(self, parent, child):
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = child

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s<-%s)' % (self.parent, self.child)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.parent, self.child))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other == None:
            return False
        return self.parent == other.parent and self.child == other.child

def __compare_parent_child(pc1, pc2):
    parent_cmp = cmp(pc1.parent, pc2.parent)
    if parent_cmp != 0:
        return parent_cmp
    child_cmp = cmp(pc1.child, pc2.child)
    return child_cmp

def __read_raw_topology():
    whitespace_re = re.compile('\s*')
    for line in __read_file_lines(__topology_file_path):
        if len(line) > 0:
            split = whitespace_re.split(line.strip())
            if len(split) != 2:
                raise __XRebaseException('syntax error: %s' % line)
            [parent, child] = split
            yield ParentAndChild(parent, child)

def __write_raw_topology(raw_topology):
    sorted_raw_topology = sorted(set(raw_topology), cmp = __compare_parent_child)
    def lines():
        for parent_and_child in sorted_raw_topology:
            yield '%s %s' % (parent_and_child.parent, parent_and_child.child)
    __write_file_lines(__topology_file_path, lines())

class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = None
        self.children = collections.OrderedDict()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other == None:
            return False
        return self.name == other.name

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s->%s->[%s])' % (self.name, self.parent.name if self.parent != None else '?', ','.join(map(lambda node: node.name, self.children.values())))

def __build_graph_index(raw_topology):
    graph_index = {}
    def get_node(name):
        if not (name in graph_index):
            node = Node(name)
            graph_index[name] = node
            return node
        return graph_index[name]
    for parent_and_child in raw_topology:
        parent_node = get_node(parent_and_child.parent)
        child_node = get_node(parent_and_child.child)
        parent_node.children[parent_and_child.child] = child_node
        child_node.parent = parent_node
    return graph_index

def __find_graph_index_roots(nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        if node.parent == None:
            yield node

def __dfs(nodes, get_children, consume, level = 0):
    for node in nodes:
        consume(node, level)
        __dfs(get_children(node).values(), get_children, consume, level + 1)

def __dfs_1_go(nodes, get_children, consume, level = 0, visited_nodes = list()):
    for node in nodes:
        if node in visited_nodes:
            raise __XRebaseException('%s causes infinite recursion' % node);
        consume(node, level)
        visited_nodes.append(node);
        __dfs_1_go(get_children(node).values(), get_children, consume, level + 1, visited_nodes)

def __do_add(parent, children):
    new_parent_and_children = list(map(lambda child: ParentAndChild(parent, child), children))
    def check(old_parent_and_child):
        if old_parent_and_child in new_parent_and_children:
            print '%s already exists' % old_parent_and_child
    raw_topology = itertools.chain(__peek(check, __read_raw_topology()), new_parent_and_children)
    __write_raw_topology(raw_topology)

def __do_clear():
    if os.path.isfile(__topology_file_path):
        os.remove(__topology_file_path)
    else:
        raise __XRebaseException('cannot clear: %s does not exist' % __topology_file_path)

def __do_help():
    print '''available commands:
    add <parent_branch> [child_branch...]
        add parent/child branch associations
    clear
        clear all parent/child branch associations
    help
        show this help
    list
        show branches list
    rebase [branch...]
        rebase branches
    remove <parent_branch> [child_branch...]
        remove parent/child branch associations
    tree
        show branches in a tree'''

def __do_list():
    for parent_and_child in __read_raw_topology():
        print parent_and_child

def __do_rebase(branches):
    if __repo.is_dirty():
        raise __XRebaseException('cannot rebase: dirty')
    graph_index = __build_graph_index(__read_raw_topology())
    nodes_to_rebase = []
    for branch in branches:
        if not (branch in graph_index):
            raise __XRebaseException('cannot found %s in %s' % (branch, graph_index.keys()))
        nodes_to_rebase.append(graph_index[branch])
    ordered_nodes_to_rebase = []
    __dfs_1_go(nodes_to_rebase, lambda node: node.children, lambda node, level: ordered_nodes_to_rebase.append(node))
    for node in ordered_nodes_to_rebase:
        if not node.name in __repo.branches:
            raise __XRebaseException('%s does not exist. deleted?' % node.name)
    original_refs = {}
    for node in ordered_nodes_to_rebase:
        original_refs[node.name] = __repo.branches[node.name].object.hexsha
    original_branch = __repo.head.ref
    success = True
    try:
        stdout_re = re.compile('^stdout: \'(.*)\'$', re.DOTALL)
        stderr_re = re.compile('^stderr: \'(.*)\'$', re.DOTALL)
        for node in filter(lambda node: node.parent, ordered_nodes_to_rebase):
            line_prefix = '%s<-%s' % (node.parent.name, node.name)
            def fix_cherry_pick():
                while True:
                    try:
                        print '%s: cherry-pick failed. trying to proceed with rebase --continue...' % line_prefix
                        __git.rebase('--continue')
                    except git.exc.GitCommandError as cherry_pick_ex:
                        cherry_pick_message_match = stdout_re.search(cherry_pick_ex.stdout.strip())
                        cherry_pick_message = (cherry_pick_message_match.group(1) if cherry_pick_message_match else '')
                        cherry_pick_error_message_match = stderr_re.search(cherry_pick_ex.stderr.strip())
                        cherry_pick_error_message = cherry_pick_error_message_match.group(1) if cherry_pick_error_message_match else ''
                        if cherry_pick_error_message.startswith('Could not pick '):
                            continue
                        elif cherry_pick_error_message == 'No rebase in progress?':
                            print '%s: cherry-pick fixed' % line_prefix
                            return True
                        elif  cherry_pick_message.find('You must edit all merge conflicts') != -1:
                            print 'please fix the conflicts and then re-run: %s' % ('git xrebase rebase %s' % ' '.join(branches))
                            return False
                        else:
                            raise __XRebaseException('cannot fix cherry-pick: %s' % str(cherry_pick_ex))
            print '%s: checkout to %s' % (line_prefix, node.name)
            __repo.branches[node.name].checkout()
            try:
                print '%s: rebase...' % (line_prefix)
                __git.rebase('-p', node.parent.name)
            except git.exc.GitCommandError as rebase_ex:
                rebase_error_message_match = stderr_re.search(rebase_ex.stderr.strip())
                rebase_error_message = rebase_error_message_match.group(1) if rebase_error_message_match else ''
                if rebase_error_message.startswith('Could not pick '):
                    if not fix_cherry_pick():
                        success = False
                        break
                elif rebase_error_message == 'Nothing to do':
                    print '%s: done' % line_prefix
                    continue
                else:
                    raise __XRebaseException('cannot rebase: %s' % rebase_error_message)
        print 'done' if success else 'could not rebase'
    except Exception as ex:
        if isinstance(ex, git.exc.GitCommandError):
            sys.stderr.write('git: %s\n' % ex.stderr.strip())
        try:
            __git.rebase('--abort')
        except git.exc.GitCommandError as git_ex:
            sys.stderr.write('git: %s\n' % git_ex.stderr.strip())
        for (branch, hexsha) in original_refs.iteritems():
            print 'recovering %s back to %s' % (branch, hexsha)
            __repo.branches[branch].checkout()
            __repo.head.reset(commit = hexsha, index = True, working_tree = True)
        raise __XRebaseException(str(ex))
    finally:
        if success:
            original_branch.checkout()

def __do_remove(parent, children):
    raw_topology = list(__read_raw_topology())
    for parent_and_child in map(lambda child: ParentAndChild(parent, child), children):
        if not (parent_and_child in raw_topology):
            print '%s not found' % parent_and_child
        else:
            raw_topology.remove(parent_and_child)
    __write_raw_topology(raw_topology)

def __do_tree():
    graph_index = __build_graph_index(__read_raw_topology())
    roots = __find_graph_index_roots(graph_index.values())
    def __print(node, level = 0):
        print '%s%s' % (' ' * level, node.name)
    __dfs(roots, lambda node: node.children, __print)

# entry point

def __dispatch(command, command_args):
    if command == 'add':
        __do_add(command_args[0], command_args[1:])
    elif command == 'clear':
        __do_clear()
    elif command == 'help':
        __do_help()
    elif command == 'list':
        __do_list()
    elif command == 'rebase':
        __do_rebase(command_args[0:])
    elif command == 'remove':
        __do_remove(command_args[0], command_args[1:])
    elif command == 'tree':
        __do_tree()
    else:
        raise __XRebaseException('unrecognized command: %s' % command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'help'
    command_args = sys.argv[2:]
    try:
        __dispatch(command, command_args)
    except __XRebaseException as ex:
        sys.stderr.write('fatal: %s\n' % ex.message)
```

I believe I missed some important things, and it would be nice to have a similar feature in `git`.