# Git: Rebase multiple sequential branches automatically

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

So let's say I have this branch structure (hashes are made up):

```
master <- ecdf4b40 <- branch1 <- branch2 <- d671270e <- branch3
```

Now let's also say `master` is no longer in sync with `origin/master`, so I have to rebase all those sequential branches.

What I do now is just rebasing the topmost branch, like this:

```
git branch branch3-bkp branch3
git checkout branch3
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Then I compare the output of `git log branch3-bkp --oneline --decorate` to `git log branch3 --oneline --decorate`, and then move branches in the middle (in this case `branch1` and `branch2`) with `git branch -f <branch-name> <hash-to-point-it-to>`.

**Is there an automatic way of rebasing all those sequential branches without having to move all inner pointers by hand (and without having to do one rebase per branch)?**

Comment: I'm not sure, but you're probably facing with the issue I try to fight with too. You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407234/git-maintaining-many-topic-branches-on-a-frequently-moving-base) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953542/is-it-possible-to-rebase-branches-along-with-their-unmerged-child-branches-in-gi). None is automatic on conflicts (at least mine), but they're probably a way to go.